# htaccess redirect all except me doesn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

everything working perfectly BUT my IP redirect as well, I need to redirect all user to the Mobile version of the site except..
so the direction working fine, but my IP redirected too!!
any suggestions?!

thanks in advance

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?DOMAIN\.com$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.DOMAIN.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the variable `%{REMOTE_ADDR}` instead of `%{REMOTE_HOST}`, which is the hostname (a canonical address).

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, it redirected me to m.Domain.com

Comment: If I'm correct, if you remove the escapes in the domain and ip, it should work. And also take into account that you have set a permanent redirect, so if you've been redirected once, your browser remembers that in the cache. So be sure to empty the cache and close your browser before trying again...